# Decompressing String method

Tags: java, loops

I need help with decompressing method. I have a working Compress method. Any suggestions as far as what I need to consider? Do I need parseInt or else....? Appreciate the advice. Here is what I have so far. If s = "ab3cca4bc", then it should return "abbbccaaaabc", for example of decompress.

```
class RunLengthCode {

private String pText, cText;

public RunLengthCode () { 
    pText = "";
    cText = "";   
}

public void setPText (String newPText) {
    pText = newPText;
}

public void setCText (String newCText) {
    cText = newCText;
}

public String getPText () {
    return pText;
}

public String getCText () {
    return cText;
}

public void compress () {     // compresses pText to cText

    String ans = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < pText.length(); i++) {

        char current = pText.charAt(i);
        int cnt = 1;

        String temp = "";

        temp = temp + current;

        while (i < pText.length() - 1 && (current == pText.charAt(i + 1))) {
            cnt++;
            i++;       
            temp = temp + current;
        }

        if (cnt > 2) {
            ans = ans + current;
            ans = ans + cnt;
        }
        else
            ans = ans + temp;

        setCText(ans);
    }
}

public void decompress () {   


}

}
public class {

public static void main(String [] args) {

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  RunLengthCode myC = new RunLengthCode();

  String pText, cText;

  System.out.print("Enter a plain text consisting of only lower-case alphabets and spaces:");
  pText = in.nextLine();
  myC.setPText(pText);
  myC.compress();
  System.out.println(pText+" => "+myC.getCText());

  System.out.print("Enter a compressed text consisting of only lower-case alphabets, spaces and digits:");
  cText = in.nextLine();
  myC.setCText(cText);
  myC.decompress();
  System.out.println(cText+" => "+myC.getPText()); 

  }
 }
```

Comment: Look for numbers in the input and repeat the last character. How far did you get implementing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create break the string into regx groups and combine them. 
The following pattern works

```
(([A-Za-z]+[\d]*))
```

This will break your string "ab3cca4bc" into groups of 
"ab3", "cca4", "bc"
So in a loop if the last character is a digit, you could multiply the character before it that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you've got an input string that looks like `ab3cca4bc`

1.) Loop over the length of the input `String`

2.) During each loop iteration, use the `String.charAt(int)` method to pick up the individual character

3.) The `Character` class has an [`isDigit(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) function that you can use to determine if a character is a number or not. You can then safely use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) (you can use `myChar+""` to convert a char into a String)

4.) If the char in question is a number, then you'll need to have an inner loop to repeat the previous character the correct number of times. How will you know what the last character was? Maybe have a variable that's instantiated outside the loop that you update each time you add a character on the end?